# How to use Regex to capitalize a street address?

Tags: javascript, regex

In my application, you can submit a street address, and in the front end I convert it all to lowercase to be stored in the database. Now when I fetch the data I get an address that looks like:
"1 pleasant valley drive"

Can I make a regex to capitalize the first letter of each word in the string?

End goal:
"1 Pleasant Valley Dr"

I'm currently using:

```
let addrFormat =
    address?.split(" ")[0] +" " +
    address?.split(" ")[1].charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
    address?.split(" ")[1].substring(1) +
    " " + address?.split(" ")[2].charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
    address?.split(" ")[2].substring(1);
```

but I need it to scale. lets say the street address is:

`1234 Rocky Mountain Road`

Then I have a problem with my code because it wont capitalize the last word.

Comment: Why regex? What if the correct address spelling isn’t with every word capitalized?

Comment: Think of "Casey's Drive",  "O'Reilly Way", "McDonald Road", "Henry XIII Alley" ... Are you still sure you don't want to store the capitalisation?

Comment: never ever change user input on user data like name, address...

Comment: Feels like an XY problem: you should solve it by _not_ forcing addresses to lowercase to begin with. You lose that bit of information that you can never recover: and can only restore it based on intelligent guesses and heuristics.

Comment: I didn't think of that, I guess I was trying to prevent user error, like if they typed in the address in all caps, I wouldn't want it displaying on the page in all caps

Comment: @eric You can still do that if you sure the original input

Comment: İf you want just show user you can do it with css `text-transform: capitalize`

Comment: Like @BIRKAN said, css `text-transform` will help solve most of presentational styling. Should you want to _validate_ the street address, you could consider a dedicated library like `address-validator` ([NPM page here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/address-validator) or an online API (examples include [this (paid)](https://www.smarty.com/products/apis/us-street-api) and [this (free)](https://www.address-validator.net/api.html). Address validation is very tricky, and I wouldn't recommend using custom regex for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply uppercase the letters that aren't proceeded by a word character.
This can be checked with a word-boundary `\b`

```js
let address = "1 pleasant valley drive";

address = address.replace(/\b(\w)/g, (m,g) => g.toUpperCase())

console.log(address);
```